# Are there modern books (or otherwise) with very strong opinions about the correct way of setting up mathematics?

Tags: reference-request, foundations

Euclid had very definite ideas about how to set up mathematics - his method involved axioms, definitions, theorems, and proofs.

Similarly, Bourbaki believed in - among other things - proceeding from maximum generality to the concrete cases. He also believed in organizing disciplines around the structures they study.

Are there modern works which, like the above, have very definite ideas about how mathematics ought to be "set up"?

Comment: What is modern if Bourbaki is not?

Comment: @RagibZaman, no more than, say 10-15 years old.

Comment: I think that maybe you can begin your quest in the nLab page about SEAR, and maybe type theoretic approaches to mathematics (e.g. Martin-Lof, although I don't know how old it is, and what written material you can find).